# LISTAGG or WM_CONCAT in Netezza

Tags: netezza

Any replacement or quick solution in NETEZZA for the Oracle function LISTAGG or WM_CONCAT ?

SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employee
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

```
DEPTNO EMPLOYEE
```

---

```
    10 JOHN,MICHEL,SAM
    20 PHILIP,FORD,SCOT,SUNNY,JOSEPH
    30 ALLEN,RUBY,BETTY,MARTIN,LEON,FRANK
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IBM provides a sample UDF/UDA that may meet your needs. Look for GROUP_CONCAT on this [page](https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/W361a40e2ccf0_43c7_b802_e51fcadaec6b/page/C__%20UDX%20Examples).

The direct link to source install file is here: [group_concat.tgz](https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/wikis/form/api/wiki/2741afdb-66df-451c-9f37-e69adccd14b1/page/471278cd-5671-4d79-b0fd-f826fd75cb36/attachment/99e8c60e-01a5-4abe-ad58-0e7c5181cc0f/media/group_concat.tgz).

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select deptno, group_concat(employee,',') from gc_test group by deptno;
 DEPTNO |            GROUP_CONCAT
--------+------------------------------------
     10 | JOHN,MICHAEL,SAM
     20 | FORD,JOSEPH,PHILIP,SCOT,SUNNY
     30 | ALLEN,BETTY,FRANK,LEON,MARTIN,RUBY
(3 rows)
```

Comment: And here we have the reason why everyone always hammers away at "don't include links - include the info" - your "this _page_" link is dead.

Comment: If only I had included the info that there is a sample UDF available in source code and included the name of the UDF and a sample of its use.

Comment: I am guilty myself of putting links into my early posts here on SO, until others reprimanded me and explained.  It's a learning process.  It's not like there is a centuries old tradition of netiquette everyone should know...