# Comma separated String list in Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, netezza, string-aggregation

Hello I am trying create comma separated list for a group of id's but not bale to do since Netezza doesn't have any Sting_Agg,LISTAGG,or group_CONCAT which can convert, is there any way through SQL i can get the result.

Data

```
ID  Attribute
1   test
1   abc
1   test2
1   test3
2   abc
2   test
3   test2
```

Result i want

```
ID   List_of_Attribute
1    test,abc,test2,test3
2    abc,test,test2
```

i tried this but it gives only one from the list no all values, i need without any string function since netezza doesn't have string aggregation function.

```
SELECT a.AC9, 
   MAX(CASE a.RNO WHEN 1 THEN a.value ELSE '' END) || 
   MAX(CASE a.RNO WHEN 2 THEN ', '||a.value ELSE '' END) 
FROM (SELECT AC9, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC9 ORDER BY value) RNO FROM table) a 
GROUP BY a.AC9
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543129/listagg-or-wm-concat-in-netezza

Comment: ID Attribute
1 test
1 abc
1 test2
1 test3
2 abc
2 test
3 test2

ID   List_of_Attribute
1    test,abc,test2,test3
2    abc,test,test2